# Compilation error on prefix header with Xcode 5.0

Tags: ios, restkit, ios7

I'm attempting to compile my project which compiled fine with the iOS 6 SDK & Xcode 4.x, however with Xcode 5 & iOS 7 SDK, I'm getting a prefix header error, below:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory:'/Users/.../IOS/Dependencies/RestKit/Code/Support/RestKit-Prefix.pch'
clang: error: no input files
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

Everything seems to be fine, other than compiling a subproject, RestKit with the app.

I've tried cleaning the project, and the build folders but to no avail.

Comment: Did you delete the DerivedData folder (after closing the project in Xcode)?

Comment: I just did that @Wain and that doesn't seem to have worked either.

Comment: Does the file exist? Is this something in the project that doesn't really exist and Xcode now considers it an error?

Comment: Seems like you have downloaded code from Github and it has dependencies with other project?